# How does a leading zero change a numeric literal in Java?

Tags: java

My friends and I have puzzled over this statement in Java after seeing it and the answer.
How does this work?

```
System.out.printf("%d", 077);
```

equals 63?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `printf`.

Comment: oracle is here for you   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Comment: @David Conrad : Yes I know, I realized that after testing it in Java after receiving the answer about 077 as an Octal Number but I only asked that because it was a test questions my friends and I had and were completely confused on.

Comment: @crAlex : have already been there before I even asked the question and that does not explain anything about Octal Numbers even though I have asked about printf.

Answer (score 7):

`077` is an [octal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) which equals 7 x 8<sup>1</sup> + 7 x 8<sup>0</sup> which is `63` decimal. To display the octal value you could do

```
System.out.printf("%o", 077);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you define an literal integer number with a 0 prefix, the compiler will treat it as an integer base 8. (Octal).

Check at this post http://rodrigosasaki.com/2013/06/10/number-literals-in-java/

So, 77 value in Octal base is actually 63 in Decimal base.

Answer (score 0):

077 = 7 * 8^0 + 7 * 8^1 = 63;
0123 = 3 * 8^0 + 2 * 8^1 + 1 * 8^2 = 3 + 16 + 64 = 83; 
First 0 means octal value.

0x77 - is hex val.